# Return number of weekdays for a specific date (Python)

Tags: python, date, calendar

I need to calculate a price based on a given date weekdays a month.
This is what im currently working with:

```
month = time.month
year = time.year
weekdays = 0
cal = calendar.Calendar()
for day in cal.itermonthdates(year, month):
  if day.weekday() == 6 and day.month == month:
    weekdays += 1
```

But this does not rely on a given date. 
I want this to return 6 for the date 10.01.2020, or 6 for 03.01.2020 or 4 for 06.01.2020.
Any help would be very nice.

Comment: `03.01.2020` means 3rd January right?

Comment: Yes! German date format.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "based on a given date weekdays a month"? I understand German if that's easier.

Comment: What does "number of weekdays for a specific date" mean?

Comment: Ich habe ein Datum und muss wissen wieviel mal dieser Wochentag im Monat vorkommt. To clarify I do not need the weekday of a given date. I need to calculate how often this weekday occurs in a month.

Answer (score 0):

Following can be a dry approach:

```
import datetime
# ...

prev_day = time.day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
month = time.month
year = time.year

cal = calendar.Calendar()
days_iterator = cal.itermonthdates(year, month)

while next(days_iterator) != prev_day:
    pass

weekdays = 0
for d in days_iterator:
  if d.weekday() == 6 and d.month == month:
    weekdays += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
d=datetime.date(2020, 1, 10) #Format YYYY, MM, DD
print(d.isoweekday())
```

Now this will print 5 not 6 as it is a Friday and the counting starts at Monday (using isoweekday instead of weekday will let the counting start by 1 instead of 0) but there should be an easy fix if you want your week begin on Sunday just add 1 and calculate modulo 7:

```
print((d.isoweekday()+1)%7)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html